# how to open multiple files in default program with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, file, operating-system

We have the function `os.startfile()` where I can pass the path to file so it would be opened in the default program if any one declared.

Now I need to open multiple files at once , using a simple for loop would open each one in a new instance or would close the previous files .

So is there a functions to which I can pass a list of paths to be opened at once?

For declaration : I need to emulate clicking on a file then pressing control then clicking on other file and finally pressing enter or using the open "open with" in file explorer.

edit: here is a photo of what i need to emulate from file explorer
[image]

edit: trying a simple for loop like this

```py
import os
my_list = [ "D:\Music\Videoder\Abyusif I أبيوسف\ِAbyusif - Kol 7aga Bteb2a Gham2a l أبيوسف - كل حاجة بتبقى غامقة.mp3",
            "D:\Music\Videoder\Abyusif I أبيوسف\Abyusif- 3ala maydoub eltalg (Prod by NGM) l أبيوسف- على ما يدوب التلج.mp3"]

for song in my_list:
    
    os.startfile(song)
```

this would open the last element in the list , as after opening each file the previous is closed

Comment: The simplest form to achieve this would be run a command on cmd. The alternative would be interact with your OS API.

Comment: @ArKan tried to use `os.system(song_name)` in a for loop which also caused the same problem and closed the previous song.. do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you could use a simple for loop.

Code:

```
import os

file_paths = ["<file path here>", "<file path here>"]
for file in file_paths:
    os.startfile(file)
```

Comment: a simple for loop like this would execute the command multiple times which would cause multiple instances of the application to be opened or the previous file to be closed , in chrome while trying to open pdf files for example a simple for loop would do the job.. however I'm trying to open some playlist in the grove music app and this code would result in opening only the last song

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you only want to execute music files, a quick and dirty way can be achieved like so:

```py
import os
import time
from win32com.client import Dispatch

my_song_list = [
    r'path\to\my\awesome\music\1.mp3',
    r'path\to\my\awesome\music\2.mp3',
    r'path\to\my\awesome\music\3.mp3'
]
wmp = Dispatch('WMPlayer.OCX')
for i, path in enumerate(my_song_list):
    song = wmp.newMedia(path)
    os.startfile(path)
    if i < len(my_song_list) - 1:
        time.sleep(song.duration)
```

Using the Windows Media Player to get the song's duration, then, running the audio file (openig with default player), and waiting exactly the duration to run the next.

Comment: I've thought in that and this seems to be the only way available thanks for your efforts

Comment: @AhmedYasser It has better ways to do this, I assure you, just takes time and research, good luck!

Comment: I'm taking some exams right now just few days and I'll search and find how to do it , thank you